# FTP/SFTP & Fuse web passthrough without using the web server's bandwidth

Tags: nginx, ftp, file-transfer, fuse, passthrough

I'd like to serve files mounted from a remote file store using ftp/sftp using fuse on my web server without using the web server's bandwidth.

The goal is to have the web server transparently serve the files to the user without providing them the original ftp information, so ftp://user:pass@example.com won't do.

Is it possible for nginx (or apache if I must) "bounce" the data to the user without using the server's bandwidth?

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible.  If you want the client to retrieve it directly they must have a direct link.  If you want to hide source then your web server will basically have to act like a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Zoredache is correct, however you can obfuscate the ftp servers a bit... and hope nobody looks too closely at the link.
There's no way to really hide the connection made to another server.  At best, you can setup DNS entries to the IP of the device... and provide links like "ftp://user:password@dnsname.yourwebdomain.tld".

I honestly can't think of any reasons to try & hide a connection to a remote server, as hackers will eventually find it regardless of weather or not you post links to it.